# Error (209015): Can't configure device. Expected JTAG ID code 0x020B10DD for device 1, but found JTAG ID code 0x000210DD

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus, cyclone

I bought from ebay Altera Cyclone II EP2C5T144 development board. It came with USB Blaster. I'm using Quartus II 13.0sp1.
FPGA is programmed with default settings as it should be (flashing onboard LEDs).

It seems like there is a byte missing in the ID. Does someone know what that is and how to fix it? Also, where is this JTAG ID from: FPGA or programmer?

I don't know if it's the same problem but when I try to Auto Detect. I get

Error (209053): Unexpected error in JTAG server -- error code 2

---

Looks like it was a typical power problem. When I connected external power to FPGA programming was successfully completed. But Auto Detect still returns the same error.

Answer (score 1):

That ID is from the FPGA itself, and hardcoded, it is used to verify that the FPGA model is exactly as configured because a bitstream for a different model might damage the FPGA (e.g. by trying to drive a pin both high and low at the same time).

Autodetection of ICs on JTAG is unreliable at best. IIRC it is implemented somewhat correctly on the CycloneII, but normally you'd configure the scan chain by hand once and never touch that button afterwards. The default configuration assumes that the chain only goes through the FPGA, which is probably correct for the evaluation board, so programming works for you.

Also, check that you are using the correct programming header. Altera has two different port mappings, one for programming the FPGA's SRAM, one for programming the configuration flash. For development, you want to use the SRAM configuration.